# Please help me with this doubt from thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

My textbook says that net rate of heat transfer due to radiation is $\epsilon \sigma A(T^4-T_o^4)$ but i couldn't understand it.

Rate of emission is $\epsilon \sigma A T^4$ and rate of absorption is $a \sigma A T_o^4$ so net rate of heat transfer must be $\epsilon \sigma A T^4 - a \sigma A T_o^4$,it is possible only if $a=e$ which means body is in thermal equilibrium.

But that is not always the case. Please help.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127586/.

Comment: @dmckee yes,the question is absolutely the same but in that thread answer was not given satisfactorily,so i have posted it again

Comment: That answer is correct. The emissivity is also the absorbtion coefficient. [It has to be by time-reversal](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/226924/520), and it is so experimentally.

Comment: @dmckee sir,that explanation is beyond by portions,so is a always equal to e?

Comment: yes, it is one  constant used a lot by engineers., it depends on the material only http://www.omega.com/temperature/Z/pdf/z088-089.pdf